# Array list or linked list which one to select

Tags: arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I was given an problem statement and the problem statement was Suppose you’re building an app for restaurants to take customer orders.

Your app needs to store a list of orders. Servers keep adding
orders to this list, and chefs take orders off the list and make them.
It’s an order queue: servers add orders to the back of the queue,
and the chef takes the first order off the queue and cooks it.
Would you use an array or a linked list to implement this queue.

I repaid linked list. Lots of inserts are happening (servers
adding orders), which linked lists excel at. You don’t need search
or random access (what arrays excel at), because the chefs always
take the first order off the queue.

Now please advise was my answer was correct and i was also thinking it mite happen that server put the ten items in queue simultaneously but at the other end chef decides that it will pick the item first which will take less time to prepare so in that case which data structure is best

Answer (score 0):

yes, linked-list should be the way to go.

This is typically because not only are you trying to insert from one end, you are also trying to remove elements from the other end.

Now in this linked list, you'll have a head and a tail, for which you'll keep their pointers always available (as you need to remove elements from tail and add elementss on top of head).

As the orders are added towards the head, the head keeps on updating : No problem here.

For the part where chef removes one order: You'll have to remove item from the list and also keep the tail pointer point to the second last object, which is now the last object in the list.

The only way in which I can think of achieving this is by using a doubly linked list, were the tail gets updated every time you remove (or pop) an element from the queue (oops sorry, linked list).

I guess that's how i was taught how to implement a queue, using a doubly linked list.

You can refer to the impelemtation [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-set-2-linked-list-implementation/).

**EDIT:**

You can do it with a singly linked list as well. Steps are:

1. Whenever a new element is added, add it to the back of the list and update the tail pointer.
2. Whenever the chef needs the element from the linked list, access the head, take out one element and update head to head-> next.

Answer (score 0):

Linked List Based Queue will be the best option for the above asked Question. In the linked list Queue you have the advantage of O(1) operation for insert(placing the orders by servers) and delete (Taking the orders by chef). Also you have dynamic memory allocation (Memory is used up only when it needs to ).

I have worked on a similar project where we used to club the similar orders which is what chefs generally do in the real world. Ex: 2 French Fries from server 1 and 3 French Fries from server2 will become 5 French Fries order in total.

When you want to Implement a scenario where random access based on the time taken for the preparation of item is considered, I still think the linked list queue will be more useful.